# Plotting a trigonometric function appears to be too slow

Tags: performance, graph, matlab

This calculates the mobility and it's derivative of one element. If I calculate with 1 value of `w`, it's very fast.

```
%**setting the equation to calculate**
    syms m w k e mi c w t L z ;
a = (((m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2 + (c * w) ^ 2) / (e * mi) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 8);
B = 1 / 4 * atan(-c * w / (m * w ^ 2 - k)) + 3.14159 / 4;
X = a * cos(B);
Y = a * sin(B);
ap = 1 / (8 * (e * mi) ^ .25) * (4 * m * w * (m * w ^ 2 - k) + 2 * c ^ 2 * w) * ((m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2 + (c * w) ^ 2) ^ (-7 / 8);
bp = 1 / 4 * (c * k + c * m * w ^ 2) / ((c * w) ^ 2 + (m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2);
xp = ap * cos(B) - a * bp * sin(B);
yp = ap * sin(B) + a * bp * cos(B);
sab = cos(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y));
sa = cos(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X));
sbb = sin(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y));
sb = sin(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X));
sabp = -L * xp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y)) + L * yp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y));
sap = -L * yp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) + L * xp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X));
sbbp = L * xp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y)) + L * yp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y));
sbp = L * yp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) + L * xp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X));
re1 = -cos(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) + sin(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y));
re4 = cos(z * Y) / 2 * (exp(z * X) - exp(-z * X)) + sin(z * X) / 2 * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y));
re2 = cos(z * Y) / 2 * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) + cos(z * X) / 2 * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y));
re3 = cos(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) - cos(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y));
im1 = -sin(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) + cos(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y));
im4 = sin(z * Y) / 2 * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) + cos(z * X) / 2 * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y));
im2 = sin(z * Y) / 2 * (exp(z * X) - exp(-z * X)) - sin(z * X) / 2 * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y));
im3 = sin(L * Y) / 2 * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) + sin(L * X) / 2 * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y));
re1p = L / 2 * cos(L * X) * xp * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y)) + L / 2 * sin(L * X) * yp * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y)) + L * yp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) - L / 2 * xp * cos(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X));
re2p = z / 2 * cos(z * Y) * xp * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) - z / 2 * sin(z * Y) * yp * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) + z * yp / 2 * cos(z * X) * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y)) - z / 2 * xp * sin(z * X) * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y));
re3p = L / 2 * cos(L * Y) * xp * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) - L / 2 * sin(L * Y) * yp * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) + L * xp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y)) - L / 2 * yp * cos(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y));
re4p = z / 2 * cos(z * X) * xp * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y)) + z / 2 * sin(z * X) * yp * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y)) + z * xp / 2 * cos(z * Y) * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) - z / 2 * yp * sin(z * Y) * (exp(z * X) - exp(-z * X));
im1p = -L / 2 * sin(L * X) * xp * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y)) + L / 2 * cos(L * X) * yp * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y)) - L * yp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) - L / 2 * xp * sin(L * Y) * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X));
im2p = z / 2 * cos(z * Y) * yp * (exp(z * X) - exp(-z * X)) + z / 2 * sin(z * Y) * xp * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) - z * xp / 2 * cos(z * X) * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y)) - z / 2 * yp * sin(z * X) * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y));
im3p = L / 2 * cos(L * Y) * yp * (exp(L * X) - exp(-L * X)) + L / 2 * sin(L * Y) * xp * (exp(L * X) + exp(-L * X)) + L * xp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) - exp(-L * Y)) + L / 2 * yp * sin(L * X) * (exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y));
im4p = -z / 2 * sin(z * X) * xp * (exp(z * Y) - exp(-z * Y)) + z / 2 * cos(z * X) * yp * (exp(z * Y) + exp(-z * Y)) + z * yp / 2 * cos(z * Y) * (exp(z * X) + exp(-z * X)) + z / 2 * xp * sin(z * Y) * (exp(z * X) - exp(-z * X));
re5 = re1 * re2 - im1 * im2;
re6 = re3 * re4 - im3 * im4;
im5 = re1 * im2 + im1 * re2;
im6 = re3 * im4 + im3 * re4;
re5p = re1p * re2 + re1 * re2p - im1p * im2 - im1 * im2p;
re6p = re3p * re4 + re3 * re4p - im3p * im4 - im3 * im4p;
im5p = re1p * im2 + re1 * im2p + im1p * re2 + im1 * re2p;
im6p = re3p * im4 + re3 * im4p + im3p * re4 + im3 * re4p;
b1 = ((re5 + re6) ^ 2 + (im5 + im6) ^ 2) ^ .5;
b2 = ((1 - sa * sab - sb * sbb) ^ 2 + (sb * sab - sa * sbb) ^ 2) ^ .5;
b1p = 2 * (re5 + re6) * (re5p + re6p) + 2 * (im5 + im6) * (im5p + im6p);
b2p = 2 * (1 - sa * sab - sb * sbb) * (-sab * sap - sa * sabp - sbp * sbb - sb * sbbp) + 2 * (sb * sab - sa * sbb) * (sbp * sab + sb * sabp - sap * sbb - sa * sbbp);
v= w * b1 / 2 / e / mi / a ^ 3 / b2;
f = 1 / 2 / e / mi / a ^ 4 / b2 ^ 2 * ((b1 + w * b1p / 2 / b1) * (a * b2) - (3 * ap * b2 + a * b2p / 2 / b2) * (w * b1));


**%Input parameter to calculate**
e=2.7*10^10;
L=21;
mi=0.001332;
z=5;
m=500;
k=1*10^7;
c=30000;
w=300;

%**calculate the v and f**
resultv = double(subs(v));
resultf = double(subs(f));
```

However, If I want to calculate velocity and accelerator with a long range of `w`, such as w(1:1:300), it take a lot of time, **more than 1 hour**. The code I add is:

```
w=linspace(0,1,300);
resultv(w) = double(subs(v));
resultf(w) = double(subs(f));
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(w,resultv)    
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(w,resultf)
```

Can anyone tell me why?  And how can I fix it to increase its speed?

Second way:

```
e=2.7*10^10;
L=21;
mi=0.001332;
z=5;
m=500;
k=1*10^7;
c=30000;
for w=1:300
    a = (((m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2 + (c * w) ^ 2) / (e * mi) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 8);
B = 1 / 4 * atan(-c * w / (m * w ^ 2 - k)) + 3.14159 / 4;
X = a * cos(B);
Y = a * sin(B);
ap = 1 / (8 * (e * mi) ^ .25) * (4 * m * w * (m * w ^ 2 - k) + 2 * c ^ 2 * w) * ((m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2 + (c * w) ^ 2) ^ (-7 / 8);
bp = 1 / 4 * (c * k + c * m * w ^ 2) / ((c * w) ^ 2 + (m * w ^ 2 - k) ^ 2);
xp = ap * cos(B) - a * bp * sin(B);
yp = ap * sin(B) + a * bp * cos(B);
sab = cos(L * X) / 2 * (cosh(L*Y));
sa = cos(L * Y) / 2 * (cosh(L*X));
sbb = sin(L * X) / 2 * (sinh(L*Y));
sb = sin(L * Y) / 2 * (sinh(L*X));
sabp = -L * xp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (cosh(L*Y)) + L * yp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (sinh(L*Y));
sap = -L * yp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (cosh(L*X)) + L * xp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (sinh(L*X));
sbbp = L * xp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (sinh(L*Y)) + L * yp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (cosh(L*Y));
sbp = L * yp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (sinh(L*X)) + L * xp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (cosh(L*X));
re1 = -cos(L * Y) / 2 * (sinh(L*X)) + sin(L * X) / 2 * (cosh(L*Y));
re4 = cos(z * Y) / 2 * (sinh(z*X)) + sin(z * X) / 2 * (cosh(z*Y));
re2 = cos(z * Y) / 2 * (cosh(z*X)) + cos(z * X) / 2 * (cosh(z*Y));
re3 = cos(L * Y) / 2 * (cosh(L*X)) - cos(L * X) / 2 * (cosh(L*Y));
im1 = -sin(L * Y) / 2 * (cosh(L*X)) + cos(L * X) / 2 * (sinh(L*Y));
im4 = sin(z * Y) / 2 * (cosh(z*X)) + cos(z * X) / 2 * (sinh(z*Y));
im2 = sin(z * Y) / 2 * (sinh(z*X)) - sin(z * X) / 2 * (sinh(z*Y));
im3 = sin(L * Y) / 2 * (sinh(L*X)) + sin(L * X) / 2 * (sinh(L*Y));
re1p = L / 2 * cos(L * X) * xp * (cosh(L*Y)) + L / 2 * sin(L * X) * yp * (sinh(L*Y)) + L * yp / 2 * sin(L * Y) * (sinh(L*X)) - L / 2 * xp * cos(L * Y) * (cosh(L*X));
re2p = z / 2 * cos(z * Y) * xp * (cosh(z*X)) - z / 2 * sin(z * Y) * yp * (cosh(z*X)) + z * yp / 2 * cos(z * X) * (sinh(z*Y)) - z / 2 * xp * sin(z * X) * (cosh(z*Y));
re3p = L / 2 * cos(L * Y) * xp * (sinh(L*X)) - L / 2 * sin(L * Y) * yp * (cosh(L*X)) + L * xp / 2 * sin(L * X) * (cosh(L*Y)) - L / 2 * yp * cos(L * X) * (sinh(L*Y));
re4p = z / 2 * cos(z * X) * xp * (cosh(z*Y)) + z / 2 * sin(z * X) * yp * (sinh(z*Y)) + z * xp / 2 * cos(z * Y) * (cosh(z*X)) - z / 2 * yp * sin(z * Y) * (sinh(z*X));
im1p = -L / 2 * sin(L * X) * xp * (sinh(L*Y)) + L / 2 * cos(L * X) * yp * (cosh(L*Y)) - L * yp / 2 * cos(L * Y) * (cosh(L*X)) - L / 2 * xp * sin(L * Y) * (sinh(L*X));
im2p = z / 2 * cos(z * Y) * yp * (sinh(z*X)) + z / 2 * sin(z * Y) * xp * (cosh(z*X)) - z * xp / 2 * cos(z * X) * (sinh(z*Y)) - z / 2 * yp * sin(z * X) * (cosh(z*Y));
im3p = L / 2 * cos(L * Y) * yp * (sinh(L*X)) + L / 2 * sin(L * Y) * xp * (cosh(L*X)) + L * xp / 2 * cos(L * X) * (sinh(L*Y)) + L / 2 * yp * sin(L * X) * (cosh(L*Y));
im4p = -z / 2 * sin(z * X) * xp * (sinh(z*Y)) + z / 2 * cos(z * X) * yp * (cosh(z*Y)) + z * yp / 2 * cos(z * Y) * (cosh(z*X)) + z / 2 * xp * sin(z * Y) * (sinh(z*X));

re5 = re1 * re2 - im1 * im2;
re6 = re3 * re4 - im3 * im4;
im5 = re1 * im2 + im1 * re2;
im6 = re3 * im4 + im3 * re4;
re5p = re1p * re2 + re1 * re2p - im1p * im2 - im1 * im2p;
re6p = re3p * re4 + re3 * re4p - im3p * im4 - im3 * im4p;
im5p = re1p * im2 + re1 * im2p + im1p * re2 + im1 * re2p;
im6p = re3p * im4 + re3 * im4p + im3p * re4 + im3 * re4p;
b1 = ((re5 + re6) ^ 2 + (im5 + im6) ^ 2) ^ .5;
b2 = ((1 - sa * sab - sb * sbb) ^ 2 + (sb * sab - sa * sbb) ^ 2) ^ .5;
b1p = 2 * (re5 + re6) * (re5p + re6p) + 2 * (im5 + im6) * (im5p + im6p);

b2p = 2 * (1 - sa * sab - sb * sbb) * (-sab * sap - sa * sabp - sbp * sbb - sb * sbbp) + 2 * (sb * sab - sa * sbb) * (sbp * sab + sb * sabp - sap * sbb - sa * sbbp);

v(w)= w * b1 / 2 / e / mi / a ^ 3 / b2;

f(w) = 1 / 2 / e / mi / a ^ 4 / b2 ^ 2 * ((b1 + w * b1p / 2 / b1) * (a * b2) - (3 * ap * b2 + a * b2p / 2 / b2) * (w * b1));
drawnow;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(v)    
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(f)

end
```

Comment: Please post some context. What exactly is it calculating, we cannot offer you a improvement unless we can be sure we are calculating the right thing.

Comment: This code is used for calculate the mobility and it's derivative of one element in the ground. a,s,sab,sabp,re,im... is cutted from the long equation to solved it better and easier. and this long equation is difficult to express here. but all the equation in my code solved the requirement correctly. However when I need it to calculate a list of "resultv" and "resultf " respectively with one value of "w" from 1-300 then plot it into the grahp, it take a lot of time to calculate (more than 1 hour). This is my  problem.

Comment: No, it's not very fast for one element, simply you don't notice any slowdown on a such a small input.

Comment: How did you "measure" that is is fast for a single parameter set? When I'm not mistaken, then feeding in constants when calling `subs` will result in the equation being computed as a constant expression - which means it is largely evaluated at compile time. Have you tried to look at how long the term gets when `w` isn't set yet?

Comment: Mr Stefano & Mr @Ext3h : I just find the other way to solved it. this is much more faster. Someone can explain the reason why this way is faster. 
update in the question

Comment: Mr @Ext3h: I don't understand what you mean. Can you help me more.

Comment: @VuNgoThanh It's probably faster because it works "different". Your first variant asked Matlab to treat `w` as a vector, virtually forcing it to unroll the entire expression and to execute it in order. Your second variant allowed the compiler to treat it as a simple expression, only containing scalars. Which enabled it to use all the nice tricks such as common subexpression elimination and alike.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you've got a lot of common subexpressions there, particularly the exponentials. Would it help to assign them to new variables?

Comment: you mean that, I replace exp(L * Y) + exp(-L * Y) with cosh(L*Y) and the other. I has tried this, but when I calculate for 1 value of w such as: w=300, matlab calculate it very fast. but when I calculate it with more value of w to plot v and f into graph, such as w=(1:1:300) it take a lot of time. more than 1 hour

Comment: You'd rather assign values to common functions, eg. you calculate `exp(-L * Y)` at least three times

Comment: @Voitcus: Thank for your help, I just find the way to solved it